# Multiple web apps deployed on separate tomcat server with a single access homepage?

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, deployment

Well, I looked and searched but didn't find what I was looking for exactly, so here it goes.

We have multiple web apps, each deployed as .war on a separate tomcat server. We're planning on creating a portal like common access page for all the apps, where users can go and select the app while the navigation menu and layout will stay the same for this common homepage. This common access point/portal will also be an app of its own.

I am curious and have been scratching my head for a while, what's the best way to approach it? The reason for deploying each app/server isolated with one another is to increase up time in case of some issue in another app.

My question is, can it be done without using portal technology? Are there any good books that discuss thes architecture/deployment strategies?

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An old fashioned way to do it would be to keep a top frame from your menu app, and use the lower portion for the other apps, but it's not recommended.
2. [Apache tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) lets you integrate page fragments, like the top menu, which you could synchronize to various servers with a [rsync](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) script.
3. Another possibility, would be to ask the fragment from the central server using an AJAX call with JSONP, to overcome the cross domain limit.
4. I suspect that since the apps are already developed it's too late for this fourth possibility, but the cleanest way to develop an app now, is writing a platform API, accessible with AJAX calls.

To clarify:

- Apart from integrating the layout, do you also want to have a common login?
- Why do you reject portal technology?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, there's single sign-on as well. I don't reject the portal technology at all, I am interested to know about other ways before going into portal and trying to keep the learning curve low for the team. Would portals like Liferay or Spring portlet do it easily?